# Azure Data Factory - Copy data - mapping - dynamic content expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i have a Copy data in ADF. It is reading pageView events in ApplicationInsight via REST API and sinking the data into a Azure SQL Table.

One of the source columns has occasionally an unwanted length and text. I'm now looking for a way to dynamically change the content of that column depending on two simple conditions.

As to my understanding this "should" be possible within the mapping by dynamically configuration some expression. However, i find myself struggling to find a proper example (surely due to lack of general knowledge around ADF).

Please have a look at the image:
[Image of Copy data mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU8aj.png)

if we take the image example "pageView.name" and at the same time i see all the possible functions i need, but the documentation linked there is not very clear in terms of how to format or reference the "current item in the loop".

Condition i would like to archive:

```
@if(length(['pageView']['name']) > 255 AND startsWith("<string to check>"))
then 
['pageView']['name'] = substr(['pageView']['name'], <length>)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking forward to transforming the data – then it’s not possible using Copy activity. Any kind of data transformations should be done using data flows only.

Copy activity mappings will help to you to map source and sink columns that’s it. Dataflows may be used where you will be able to have derived column transformation and conditional split transformations to achieve your goal.

Note: Use the derived column transformation to generate new columns in your data flow or to modify existing fields.

[image]

Where you will be able to dynamically add expression for the column:

[image]

Please referto the Microsoft Document : Transform data using mapping data flows | [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Additional columns in the Source, Choose 'Add dynamic content' from the drop down and add your conditions.
[image: Sample Additional column]